# Building a graph with custom ops in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to explore use of tensorflow with custom ops. I build a simple switch op and verified it as suggested in tensorflow document. Now I'm trying to build the graph and then call `run()` method in a tensorflow 
Session. Below is my code. I get the following error. Can someone help what should I do to fix it. Do I need to re-install tensorflow everytime I add a new custom op to `/user_ops/`?

```
import tensorflow as tf 

# Create a Constant op that produce integer value
input1 = tf.constant(10)

# Create another op that produce an integer value
input2 = tf.constant(5)

# Create op that produce 0 or 1 as the control input in a switch
input3 = tf.constant(1)

# Create a switch op that takes input1 and input2 as inputs and input3 as 
# the control input to produce an output
out = tf.user_ops.simple_switch(input1, input2, input3)


# Launch a default graph
sess = tf.Session()

# Call the 'run()' method and get the result
result = sess.run(out)
print(result)


# Close the Session when we're done!
sess.close()
```

When executed in python interpreter I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "tensorflow-switch.py", line 14, in 
>       out = tf.simple_switch(input1, input2, input3)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'simple_switch'

Comment: What does the edited `user_ops` look like?

Comment: @Caridorc  Do you mean my custom op?

Comment: I mean: Did you just add a free floating function to that module or added it in a class or dictionary?

Comment: I added it in a class. Below is a snippet from my custom op: class SimpleSwitchOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit SimpleSwitchOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}
  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // Grab the input tensor
    const Tensor& input_tensor_x = context->input(0);
    auto input_x = input_tensor_x.flat<int32>();

    const Tensor& input_tensor_y = context->input(1);
    auto input_y = input_tensor_y.flat<int32>();
    const Tensor& input_tensor_control = context->input(2);
    auto input_control = input_tensor_control.flat<int32>();

Comment: Below where exactly?

Comment: class SimpleSwitchOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit SimpleSwitchOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // Grab the input tensor
    const Tensor& input_tensor_x = context->input(0);
    auto input_x = input_tensor_x.flat<int32>();

    const Tensor& input_tensor_y = context->input(1);
    auto input_y = input_tensor_y.flat<int32>();

    const Tensor& input_tensor_control = context->input(2);
    auto input_control = input_tensor_control.flat<int32>();

Comment: I build a test as suggested in tutorial and it passed

Comment: I fear that the use of C(++) code will force you to recompile when you modify such code.

Comment: I see so I should uninstall and re-install tensorflow with a pip whl?

Comment: I suggest just waiting for now. Someone more experienced than me will surely come and give you a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [adding a user-defined op](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html) (in TensorFlow 0.6.0 or earlier), to use it in the Python interpreter you must reinstall from the source repository. The easiest way to do this is to [build and install a PIP package](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#create-pip) using Bazel. (The unit test would pass because running `bazel test` would cause TensorFlow to be rebuilt, and the rebuilt version to be used when running the tests.)

**NOTE:** This feature is experimental, and an improved workflow for adding user-defined ops is in development.